# All well known aliases for localhost?

Tags: sql-server, windows, ip

The primary goal is determine whether machine is local or remote by machine name.

I have to complete a list with all well known aliases of `localhost`.
So here I am:

```
var localAddressList = new List<string>
                    {
                        @"(local)",
//                      @"(localdb)",
                        @"(localhost)",
                        @"localhost",
//                      @"localhost -4",
//                      @"localhost -6",
                        @"127.0.0.1",
                        @"::1",
                        @"."
                    };
```

But I am not sure about commented aliases.
Do you know another aliases ?
Can anyone share with me where to find this information ?

Comment: I don't know where to find a list, but you should also think about `localhost.localdomain`

Comment: @xanoetux thanks, but what about commented aliases ? I can't connect to sql server via ssms using those aliases.

Comment: Local vs remote is relative. "local" means something different based on where the connection is. It is sort of like asking "are we there yet". Of course you aren't "there" because you are always here. And of course any name you find could also be a named instance on that server. You would be far better served by evaluating @@SERVERNAME. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can check your DNS Server definitions and your SQL Server Aliases definitions.
SQL Browser will check for SQL Server hostname and aliases.

Inside `Sql Server Configuration Manager` go to `SQL Native Client XX.0 Configuration (XXbit)` then `Aliases` section.

Also any computer with a modified hosts file or another DNS Server could address the server with another name (this does not mean SQL Browser will answer properly though).

Make sure to check the following file it might contain your desires :

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: If anyone has a reference documentation on how SQL Browser handle aliases fell free to edit

Comment: but this is for sql instance

Comment: You tagged `sql-server` didn't you ?